# How do I create a new texture image from another one?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking

my goal here is to include a .obj of a large mesh in UE4.
The initial problem is that my texture image resolution is 16384 ² and UE4 only goes up to 8192 ².

The obvious way to go under a texture of 16384 ² for me is to cut the original mesh into smaller meshes (also the advice I got).

So I did cut my mesh in 4, tried to import one part into UE4 and it told me the texture image was still 16384 ².

I did some research and found that even if I divide the mesh, it will keep the original texture image. I then saw that cycles allows to bake a new texture from the original, but the output was still in a 16384 ² resolution, it just blacked out the unused pixels.

My question is then : how can I divide my mesh and get a smaller texture image?